My question "Making title attribute of HTML elements display as text instead of as tooltips" was removed as off-topic; where can I ask it?
My question "Making title attribute of HTML elements display as text instead of as tooltips" was removed as off-topic with the explanation that "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center".
I disagree, as this is indeed a question about computer software and is an end user question, not a software developer question, that I feel does fall within the scope defined in the help center and doesn't fall into any of the listed exceptions. And at least one other user seems to agree with me, since someone upvoted the question before it was closed.
In any case, though, if this question has to be closed, then on what StackExchange site should I ask this question instead?

From the html tag description

You may ask questions about handling HTML files; however, questions regarding HTML markup are considered off topic here.

Questions about coding web pages and website design belong at Stack Overflow
There is also Webmasters for questions about managing websites.


Re:"Questions about coding web pages and website design belong at Stack Overflow / There is also Webmasters for questions about managing websites." But this is not a question about coding web pages or website design or managing websites, which are all things done at the server end. This is a question from the end user side. I actually considered both those suggestions beforehand and didn't post my question there because I thought my question was better fit on this StackExchange than those StackExchanges.


Regarding "questions regarding HTML markup are considered off topic here": This isn't a question about HTML markup. It's an end user question about browser configuration to change how a website displays, and as such, SuperUser is the right StackExchange for this question. Anyway, I tried posting my same question at Webmasters, and my question also got removed there as off-topic.

You're also assuming that there is only one reason that your question was closed. That is only the case sometimes. The site will highlight the reason selected by most of those voting to close a question.
As commentors on your post noted, your question lacks information regarding what you have tried so far in your own attempts to solve this, records of the research you have done, or any other self-effort.
I agree with those saying this is a borderline question regarding topicality, and if it were a well presented question with more clarity and detail, it would not likely have been closed for being off topic.
The edits you made prior to submitting for reopening do not address this lack of detail or clarity.
